# How to load .bytes saved model in unity,which is frozen in tnesorflow1.4 to the unity enivronment?

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, tensorflow

I am trying to load a saved custom object detection model inside unity. I am training the model in `tensorflow 1.12` and freezing the graph in `1.4` as only `1.4` is compatible with unity.

Here is my code.

`

```
pixels = new byte[INPUT_SIZE  INPUT_SIZE  3];
 _catalog = CatalogUtil.ReadCatalogItems(labelMap.text);
       Debug.Log("LabelMap Text : " + labelMap.text);
       Debug.Log("Loading graph...");
       graph = new TFGraph();
       graph.Import(model.bytes);
       session = new TFSession(graph);
       Debug.Log("Graph Loaded!!!");`
```

My unity version is `2017` the tensorflow plugin is `0.4`

Here is my error trace.

```
`TFException: NodeDef mentions attr 'Truncate' not in Op<name=Cast; signature=x:SrcT -> y:DstT; attr=SrcT:type; attr=DstT:type>; NodeDef: Postprocessor/ToFloat_2 = Cast[DstT=DT_FLOAT, SrcT=DT_INT32, Truncate=false](Postprocessor/ToFloat_2/x). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).

TensorFlow.TFStatus.CheckMaybeRaise (TensorFlow.TFStatus incomingStatus, System.Boolean last) (at <1fe2de69842a4a4ba15256b83cca05f3>:0)`
```

Is this because we are training in one version and freezing in another version?.

How to solve this issue?.

Comment: Your unity version is 0.4?? are you really sure of that?

Comment: Sorry the unity version is 2017 but the tensorflow plugin used is `0.4`